# Python Classes: Differences Between Explicitly Writing Attributes Inside __init__() Parentheses

Tags: python, class, oop

I am a Python beginner grinding through Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes.  I am currently on chapter 9 Classes and Object Oriented Programming.

I have the following code:

```
class User: # Define the class
"""A simple attempt to model website users."""

def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, username, city, country):
    self.first_name = first_name.title()
    self.last_name = last_name.title()
    self.age = age
    self.username = username
    self.city = city.title()
    self.country = country.title()
    self.login_attempts = 0
```

I understand that Python calls the `__init__()` method to create a new instance, stores the `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, `username`, `city`, and `country` attributes.  The author says that Python creates a new attribute called `login_attempts`.

The author only shows this method, but I've seen some people online explicitly write the `login_attempts` attribute inside the `__init__()` method.  Is there any difference between the two approaches?  Is one of the approaches considered a "best practice?"  I'd like to build good habits before I inconvenience people who use my code.  Thank you!

Comment: If `login_attempts` is _intended_ to always start at zero, as seems to be the case here, then there would be no use in providing it as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, @JohnGordon  You are correct.  `login_attempts` is intended to always start at zero.  Thank you for explaining this logic to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the class.  If you add `login_attempts=0` in the argument list, that would allow a caller to specify their own value.  However, many variables defined in `__init__` are for internal use, and there is no point in allowing them to be overridden.  Also, remember that if you JUST add `login_attempts` by itself, then the caller MUST supply a value.  That's why I added the default (`=0`).

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, @TimRoberts.  I hadn't thought about the point you made, that variables defined in the __init__() parentheses would mean that the users would be able to change the value, and that many variables are only for internal use.  The learning never stops!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a parameter, then it's expected (actually, required) that the caller will pass in data as an argument. That's what the parameters of a function are for: they specify what data the function requires to do its action. In the case of the inializer method `__init__`, it specifies what data is required to initialize the object being created.

Here though, `login_attempts` is always initialized to 0, since, presumably, there are always 0 attempts until a user makes an attempt. 0 seems like a good default since a count is always 0 before you start counting; so it isn't necessarily useful to be forced to specify the starting value of a sum.

In some cases, it may make sense to pass the data in to ease testing (you may want to test what happens when a user with, say, two login attempts attempts a third), but if you aren't at the point where you're worried about ease of testing, do you need to allow the caller to specify what `login_attempts` should start as?

Comment: This explanation makes a ton of sense, @Carcigenicate!  The parameters inside the parentheses are required for the program to work.  Without them, I'll get errors that there are not enough arguments.  The people using this program don't need to input a number of login attempts, that number is saved, but the person who uses the program does not need to touch it.  Thank you!